# JS - TypeError: value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, typeerror, iterable

I am new to JS and i need to do a API POST request from a HMI Panel (Weintek) that support JS.
I need to create an object with a defined structure inside for the data of the machine.

[image: This is how I created the Object (objWebApi) that contains other variables and other Objects]

I tried to structured the code to dinamically get the string that i need to send.

Initially I create a dict to contain my final data to send with a stringify.
Then I iterate on the variables in the first "layer" (sorry for my english), so name, id, description, etc..

```
// initialize final object to send
var objWebApi_Final = {

};

// Subscription - Read and Elaboration of data
this.config.Sub_GetData.onResponse(async (Sub_GetData_Err, Sub_GetData_Data) => {

    if (Sub_GetData_Err) {
        logger.log("Sub_GetData - ERROR: ", err.message);
    } else {
        let command = Sub_GetData_Data.values[0];
        // Do the rest if the value of Subscription goes OFF -> ON
        if (command === 1) {

            // Counting the number of object declared for this.config.objWebApi
            const objectCount = Object.keys(this.config.objWebApi).length;

            // Declaring a var for counting for iterations
            var i = 0;
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.config.objWebApi)) {
                objWebApi_Final, i = await elaborate(objWebApi_Final, this.config, key, value, true, i, objectCount);
            };
        };
    };
});
```

I call the function elaborate:

```
async function elaborate(dict, config, Key, Value, isPrimitive, i, objectCount) {
    var type = resolveType(Value);
    if (type === "Object") {
        var tempDict = {};
        var nameObj = (Key).toString();
        const objectCount_internal = Object.keys(Value).length;

        for await (const [key, value] of Object.entries(Value)) {
            tempDict, i = await Promise.all(elaborate(tempDict, config, key, value, false, i, objectCount_internal));
        dict[nameObj] = tempDict;
        };
    } else {
        if (type === "Subscription") {
            if (isPrimitive === true) {
                dict, i = getData_String(config, Key, Value, dict, i, objectCount);
            } else {
                dict = getData_SubElement_String(Key, Value, dict);
            };
        } else {
            if (Value.dataType === 0){
                if (isPrimitive === true) {
                    dict, i = getData_Bit(config, Key, Value, dict, i, objectCount);
                } else {
                    dict = getData_SubElement_Bit(Key, Value, dict);
                };
            } else {
                if (isPrimitive === true) {
                    dict, i = getData_Word(config, Key, Value, dict, i, objectCount);
                } else {
                    dict = getData_SubElement_Word(Key, Value, dict);
                };
            };
        };
    };

    if (isPrimitive === true && type === "Object") {
        i = i + 1;
        // Call the function for sending data
        await Promise.all(callRequest(dict, objectCount, i));
    };
    return dict, i;
};
```

I paste here one of the GetData Function (are all pretty similar).

```
async function getData_String(config, key, value, dict, i, objectCount) {
    var length = value.length;
    var address = value.address;

    var utf8decoder = new TextDecoder();
    await driver.promises.getData(address, length).then((valoreAcquisito) => {
        var bufferAsUint8Array = new Uint8Array(valoreAcquisito.buffer);
        dict[key] = utf8decoder.decode(bufferAsUint8Array);
        dict[key] = dict[key].replace('\0', '').replace(/\0/g, '');
        i = i + 1;
        // Call the function for sending data
        callRequest(config, objectCount, i);
    });
    return dict, i;
};
```

**My problem is:**
When I encounter an object, like "SOTTO" in my example, i call again the function "elaborate", with key and value as parameters.
I get an error:
**TypeError: value is not iterable**
**at all (native)**
**at elaborate (:103)**

I started reading stuff like generators/iterators, Map, but I can't solve this error (also because i didn't understand so much about iterators and others..).

Thank you in advance.